# Move values to column based on row value

Tags: awk

The input file the date block change every each 4 lines (column 1). Example for days 061218 and 061418, **but not in the case for date 061318**, which contends 8 lines.

Then in the case where the date does not change after 5 lines,like the example on date 061318 in that case the values of the second part **lines 5-8** need to be added to the END ond the **lines 1-4**. To get correctly in the output file desired.

**Input file**

```
061218,2660,2660,2661
061218,0,0,0,0
061218,48,30,569
061218,SD/05,F1/R0,SD/05
061318,2654,2654
061318,0,0
061318,114,60
061318,SD/05,F1/R0
061318,2666
061318,0
061318,1
061318,F1/R0
061418,2648,2648,2649
061418,0,0,0
061418,871,868,876
061418,SD/05,F1/R0,SD/05
```

**Output file**

```
061218,2660,2660,2661
061218,0,0,0,0
061218,48,30,569
061218,SD/05,F1/R0,SD/05
061318,2654,2654,2666
061318,0,0,0
061318,114,60,1
061318,SD/05,F1/R0,F1/R0
061418,2648,2648,2649
061418,0,0,0
061418,871,868,876
061418,SD/05,F1/R0,SD/05
```

**I tried:**

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' OFS=, file
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can there be 12/16/etc lines for a particular date? also, you have to **show** what you have tried to solve this..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Sundeep.The date block change every each 4 lines this will be fixed. I have tried something like this:  awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' OFS=, file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample(which you mentioned in your comments it is) then could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   FS=OFS=","
}
prev!=$1 && prev{
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
     print prev,a[prev,i]
   }
   prev=count=""
}
{
   prev=$1
   sub(/[^,]*,/,"")
   if(count==4){
     count=1
   }
   else{
     count++
   }
   a[prev,count]=a[prev,count]?a[prev,count] OFS $0:$0
}
END{
   if(prev){
     for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
        print prev,a[prev,i]
     }
   }
}'  Input_file
```

Change above `a[prev,count]` line to `a[prev,count]=(a[prev,count]?a[prev,count] OFS:"")$0` in Ed Morton sir's style too, to shorten and make it compatible to other `awk`s too.